# fastest way to see if a string is found in a file?

Tags: php, unix, filesystems

Let's say I have a big file. The file is a list of IPs each on a new line like this:

```
123.123.123.123
123.123.123.124
123.123.123.125
etc...
```

I could do it like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents($src);    
if (substr_count($file,'myip'))
    echo 'FOUND';
```

Or a similar way with array style:

```
$file = file($src,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (in_array('myip',$file))
    echo 'FOUND';
```

But I think **there is** a third alternative that could be faster.
Parsing the file line by line and of course stopping the reading if the string is found.

Something like this:

```
$file = fopen($src,'r');
while(!feof($file)) { 
    $ip = fgets($file);
    if ($ip == $myIP) {
        die('Found');
    }   
}
fclose($file);
```

My question is: do you think there are other better way?

And performance-wise which code do you think is faster?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: There is no way of using a command-line tool like `grep` or `find` instead?

Comment: if you think it could be faster I believe i can use it..

Comment: It is hard to speculate which one is faster, why don't you try to test it out? You have 3 very clear ideas which all should work. Do it a thousand times and time it :).

Comment: grep is probably faster than anything you write yourself.

Comment: The first 2 methods map the entire file into memory (or at least try to) - which is not going to work with big files, nor is it very efficient if the search string is near the top of the file. The 3rd approach puts the flow of control into your code - so it'll be rather slow as it processes PHP source code in for each operation. Like peka says - if (`grep $myIP $file`) die ('found');

Comment: (there should be backticks around the grep command above)

Comment: hi sym. What if there is a line with `112.1.1.1` and I search for `12.1.1.1` ?

Comment: Grep can handle all that using regular expressions. (I don't know the syntax but I assume it's something like `$12\.1\.1\.1`)

Comment: If this has to be run by a webserver you can't do it faster then your 3rd solution. Even if you can `shell_exec('fgrep -l')` it's likely more costly then opening a file handle and scanning lines.

Comment: @mel: are you saying that using grep is slower than my 3rd solution? and yes php in this situation is runned by apache

Comment: Yes, fgrep should be slower when forked from PHP. Simply because popen = fopen+fork() and the rest of the operations are the same. Maybe fgrep can catch up on large files, because comparing strings in PHP is slower then fgrep's matching, but you'd have to benchmark the cut-off and decide if this is worth spawning a process for (which counts against a system's maximum nr. of processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, consider using [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or [`find`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_%28command%29). It might be faster and, more importantly, more memory-efficient than PHP.

Comment: yo pekka i believe you have no willing to do a test case? eh xD

Comment: pekka: I believe grep can't be faster than my 3rd solution. Because grep will search until the end of file and it will not stop at the first occurence

Comment: @yes grep has parameters for that. See `-l` in http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fgrep

Comment: I am going to accept this But i don't think it's the best case here because if you need a lot of searches the forking routine overhead will impact

Comment: @yes I don't think it necessarily has to be - depends on how large your files are, how many, and how many files you would process with one call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming doing this in a language is a requirement, a modification of your line-by-line code would probably be best, so you're not grabbing any more data than you need.

```
$file = fopen($src,'r');
while(!feof($file)) { 
    $ip = fgets($file);
    if ($ip == $myIP) {
        echo 'FOUND!';
        break; // dieing here won't close the file
    }   
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: man do you know at end of the php script all resources are freed automatically?

Comment: If someone takes the code structure they see here and use it in another language (like C), the same may not hold. Teaching proper conventions to passing readers is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you could keep the file sorted, then performing a binary search would perform well.

However, sorting the file will take some time, so if you are doing a lot of inserts/deletes it might not be very effective.

Comment: hm this could be interesting... anyway i never delete item i just do insert (i delete the entire file with some interval)